# docker install container-selinux hang on centos

Tags: docker, centos, containers, yum

i have centos 7 (on Xen) and I'm trying to install the latest stable update.
first thing that I did is to stop the docker service and remove old versions from the [procedure](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/centos/)

then I have tried to install docker-ce using the command (I have already added the docker repo):

```
sudo yum install docker-ce
```

from some reason the installation hang.

command output:

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks Loading mirror speeds from
>   cached hostfile  * base: repo1.ash.innoscale.net  * epel:
>   mirror.us.leaseweb.net  * extras: mirror.rackspace.com  * updates:
>   ftp.osuosl.org Resolving Dependencies There are unfinished
>   transactions remaining. You might consider running
>   yum-complete-transaction, or "yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only"
>   and "yum history redo last", first to finish them. If those don't work
>   you'll have to try removing/installing packages by hand (maybe
>   package-cleanup can help).
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 0:17.09.0.ce-1.el7.centos will be installed
>   --> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2.9 for package: docker-ce-17.09.0.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package container-selinux.noarch 2:2.28-1.git85ce147.el7 will be installed
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Dependencies Resolved
>
> =================================================================================================================================================================================  Package                                     Arch
>   Version                                           Repository
>   Size
>   ================================================================================================================================================================================= Installing:  docker-ce                                   x86_64
>   17.09.0.ce-1.el7.centos                           docker-ce-stable                            21 M Installing for dependencies:  container-selinux
>   noarch                           2:2.28-1.git85ce147.el7
>   extras                                      29 k
>
> Transaction Summary
>   ================================================================================================================================================================================= Install  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)
>
> Total size: 21 M Installed size: 76 M Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
>   Downloading packages: Running transaction check Running transaction
>   test Transaction test succeeded Running transaction   Installing :
>   2:container-selinux-2.28-1.git85ce147.el7.noarch

the installation hang on container-selinux.
after stopping (I have waited 1 hour) the yum install process I'm getting the error:

> warning: %post(container-selinux-2:2.28-1.git85ce147.el7.noarch)
>   scriptlet failed, signal 2 Non-fatal POSTIN scriptlet failure in rpm
>   package 2:container-selinux-2.28-1.git85ce147.el7.noarch

now here is the strange thing... actually after stopping the process the container-selinux has been installed (not sure if successfully)
so after that I was able to install docker-ce without issue but only after interrupt the fist installation that was hang

any idea how to complete the installation without the be hanging?

remarks:

1) already tried reboot

2) already tried to install using the command: yum install --setopt=obsoletes=0 docker-ce

3) the repository extras already enabled

4) no disk space or performance issue on the server

5) already tried: yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only

6) there is already containers + volumes that their data (under /var/lib/docker/) is still exist on disk

Answer (score 3):

after several hours of trying things to make the installation work without hanging I have succeeded only after **yum update** all the packages in the server

looks like that the package (in my case) container-selinux-2.28-1.git85ce147.el7.noarch.rpm ([here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/)) contains some Requirements of the packages ([here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-extras-x86_64/container-selinux-2.28-1.git85ce147.el7.noarch.rpm.html)):

```
libselinux-utils
policycoreutils >= 2.5-11
policycoreutils-python
selinux-policy >= 3.13.1-39
selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-39
selinux-policy-targeted >= 3.13.1-39
```

I didn't try to update only them but probably it will do the work

Comment: did it work? I'm having the same issue now with 2.68

Comment: for reference, for me I had to kill the `restorecon -R /var/lib/docker` to let it through

Comment: Oddly, running `sudo strace -f yum reinstall container-selinux` got it to complete for me.

Comment: @TecHunter thanks, stopping the Docker service allowed it to proceed for me.